# Check if at least two element in array are equal

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

Is there a way to check that at least one element appears more than once in an array are equal without sequentially comparing every element.

Example: In int[] array1 = { 1, 3, 4, 2, 4 }; the element `4` appears twice.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired output.

Comment: `if (new Set(array).Count != array.Length) {...}`

Comment: @DoThanhTung : check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if there is any difference between original array and it's `Distinct()` version.

```
  var result = (array1.Count()-array1.Distinct().Count())>0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
var duplicates = array1.GroupBy(p => p).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key);
```

variable `duplicates` contains the list of repeated items

**EDIT**

If you want to the return value to be Boolean than

```
var duplicates = array1.GroupBy(p => p).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key).Count() > 0;
```

You can also do something like this

```
if(array1.Distinct().Count() != array1.Count())
    return true; /// You have duplicates in the array 
else
    return false; /// All the elements in the array are different
```

Comment: Sorry but i want compare in an array.

Comment: since you update your question I'll update my answer

Comment: How can I do if I want return value is bool type

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Distinct()`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/distinct) method to get unique values of array and compare length with original array

```
int[] arrayDistinctElements = array1.Distinct().ToArray();

if(arrayDistinctElements.length == array1.length)
{
//All unique elements
}
else
{
//Duplicates were present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
var isExisted = list.Count(item => item.Param == "test") >= 2;
```

Sample solution in your case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1y4w9K

Comment: I edited my question. In my case, I don't have an exactly value like "test". I only want check two elements in an array are equal.